# How To Install Perl 5.30 in RHEL 7.7 Docker container

Tags: linux, docker, perl, installation, rhel

I want to install Perl v5.30 in my RHEL 7.7 container image.
So i tried

```
#yum install -y perl 
perl-5.16.3-294.el7_6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
```

I'm able to install  perl-5.16.3. But how can I install v5.30 instead of v5.16.3?

I am completely new to Perl. Thanks in advance

Comment: Look into perlbrew for installing versions newer than the one provided by your OS.

Comment: Hi Shawn, Thanks for your help and it really worked . But I'm facing some delay  for installing the package through perlbrew  .Can't we install it  using ''yum'' after updating the repo

Comment: Is there anything specific you are missing in Perl 5.26 that are present in 5.30? If these are not essential, `conda` is often an install method of choice due to its ease and flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to install from `yum`, then I'm afraid that you're stuck with Perl 5.16 on RHEL7. But there are a couple of solutions that spring to mind.

- Create your own RPM of a newer version of Perl and then create your own package repo that only contains that package. I'd recommend building it so that the newer Perl is installed in a different location to the existing system Perl.
- Create a Docker image that is built on the RHEL7 image, but that adds `perlbrew` and the version of Perl that you want. Then use that image instead of the official RHEL one.

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with a slightly older Perl version (5.26 as of this writing, rather than 5.30 as you mentioned), try `conda install perl`: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/perl/

Answer (score 0):

If Perl 5.26 will work, then [install](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/hello-world#fndtn-perl) Perl 5.26 via [Software Collections](https://developers.redhat.com/products/softwarecollections/updates) which are part of the RHEL subscription.